# Propagating exceptions when using generators and promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, exception, promise, generator

This question is about emulating the behavior of `async`/`await` by using generators and promises, as described here:
https://gist.github.com/ChrisChares/1ed079b9a6c9877ba4b43424139b166d

Here is the minimal example exposing the problem:
<sub>The function `async` is taken verbatim from the link above.</sub>

```js
function async(gen, context = undefined) {
 const generator = typeof gen === 'function' ? gen() : gen; // Create generator if necessary
 const { value: promise } = generator.next(context); // Pass last result, get next Promise
 if ( typeof promise !== 'undefined' ) {
  promise.then(resolved => async(generator, resolved))
  .catch(error => generator.throw(error)); // Defer to generator error handling
 }
}

function timesTwoPlusOne(num){ //multiplies argument by 2 and adds one, asynchronously
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  async(function*(){
   //throw 'Fake exception 1' ;
   num = yield Promise.resolve( 2*num ) ; //multiply by 2, asynchronously
   //throw 'Fake exception 2' ;
   resolve( num + 1 ) ; //add one, synchronously
  }) ;
 });
}

//run an asynchronous procedure
async(function*(){
 let result ;
 try{
  result = yield timesTwoPlusOne(10) ;
 }catch(e){
  //the intention is to catch any exception happening inside `timesTwoPlusOne`
  console.log('CATCHED:', e) ;
 }
 console.log( result ) ;
}) ;
```

The code as it is, works fine. It prints `21` as expected.
However, inside the function `timesTwoPlusOne` there are two lines commented out.

When we uncomment the first one (`throw 'Fake exception 1'`) and try again, that exception propagates up and is caught by the only `catch` block in the whole code.

That's exactly what I want. So far, so good.

But now, if we uncomment the second line (`throw 'Fake exception 2'`) and leave the first one commented out, that exception IS NOT caught.

Why is the `try/catch` block able to catch the first exception, but not the second one?